# Face cropping along the face edge

Tags: ios, swift, face-detection, apple-vision

Before anyone rates this question negative, let me clarify that I have tried all the resources possible in last two weeks before posting this query. And also I've never done this stuff previously and I don't have someone to guide me anyhow currently and I just have a few months of experience in iOS.

Now, the query is, I'm **trying to crop a face along the face edges** using **vision API**. I've found little help from this URL [https://github.com/artemnovichkov/iOS-11-by-Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUvQC.png)
[image]

Using which I'm also able to do what's already done in above link. i.e. marking along the edge of the face.

My goal is to crop only the face along the edges.
My final goal is to make a sketch (Something like: [image]

or apply some filters on the cropped face. For more reference kindly search for bobble app on play store or app store.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @DuncanC how do I crop only the face inside face contour?

Comment: Can you please provide and example of what you want (an image being better than words etc etc), and maybe what you have tried so far, and what doesn't work? Otherwise people like me might suggest trivial stuff that you might have already tried. I mean, if you don't have real-time constraints, just go for brute force...

Comment: @Ash my final aim is to create something like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5i8ucWVEuUc/hqdefault.jpg , i have tried vision API, core images,  to get face edges, but I'm not able to crop the face in it's shape.. I can crop in a rectangle shape but that's not what we need.

Comment: I think this is far from trivial since you will have to be able to do that robustly regardless of many variations in your input (different hairstyles, forehead sizes, color and illumination). I'm almost sure that what you are doing now wont be sufficient. Personnaly I would try to train some network for this task... However, I'm not up to date with the face recognition litterature, so I can only suggest  that you add the image to the question itself, it will increase the likelihood of getting an answer.

Comment: @Ash Thank you. people like you make Stack overflow an amazing place.